# How to make LinearLayout height to be the highest height of it's child component?

Tags: android, android-layout

I add two Checkboxes dynamically to a Linearlayout. Then those Linearlayouts are added one after another in a Relativelayout. The weights of the checkboxes are set so that each take 50% of the Linearlayout width. Now, if their heights do not match, the bottom of the checkbox with bigger height disappears. How to solve this? Here's a screenshot:

[image]

And the code:

```
LinearLayout ll;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    CheckBox ch;
    int id = 1200, i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < selections.size() - 1; i += 2, j += 2) {
        ll = new LinearLayout(NotificationSettings.this);
        lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ch = new CheckBox(NotificationSettings.this);
        lp.weight = 1.0f;
        ch.setLayoutParams(lp);
        ch.setText(selections.get(i));
        ch.setChecked(isSelected);
        ch.setTextColor(color);
        ch.setId(j);
        ll.addView(ch);
        ch = new CheckBox(NotificationSettings.this);
        ch.setLayoutParams(lp);
        ch.setText(selections.get(i + 1));
        ch.setChecked(isSelected);
        ch.setTextColor(color);
        ch.setId(j + 1);
        ll.addView(ch);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        if (id == 1200)
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, addBelow);
        else
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id);
        ll.setLayoutParams(p);
        ll.setId(++id);
        rl.addView(ll);
    }
```

**Edit:**
When both checkboxes have multiple lines:

[image]

Comment: layout xml codes please ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that the Linear Layout's height below it is not too large that it covers the above Linear Layout?

Or try changing your Relative Layout Params' height to `WRAP_CONTENT`

Change

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

To

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: WRAP_CONTENT didn't work. And in the screenshot above, you can see that there is not any more Linearlayouts.

Comment: I'm pertaining the layout below what you highlighted on your image. The container Layout of the one with "Select Type" and a gear button on the right below.

Comment: I don't think the layout below is overtaking. I have edited the question with a screenshot which shows checkboxes with multiple lines. See, the problem doesn't occur here.